# Prove If $x^2\equiv 1 \bmod 3$ then $x$ is even

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $x^2\equiv1 \bmod 3$ then $x$ is even. I dont understand how to prove if this is right or wrong. Thanks

Comment: What about $x \in \{1, 7, 13, 19, \cdots\}?$

Comment: 1 mod 3= 1, and the square root of 1 is 1 or -1. Either way, it is odd.

Comment: $7^2=49$ And $49-1=16\cdot 3$ so $7^2\equiv 1\mod 3$. this bad question has been asked yesterday.

Comment: In fact, the first part holds iff $x$ is indivisible by $3$.

Comment: In addition to the above comments, we can have things like $x\equiv y\pmod 3$ but $x$ and $y$ have different parity (e.g. $x=2, y=5$).

Comment: What is the source of this question? It appeared [yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3878662/if-x2-equiv-1-mod-3-then-x-is-even)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK let's just try some numbers $1^{2}=1$ is congruent to $1$ mod $3$ and is odd. $2^{2}=4$ is also congruent to $1$ mod $3$. $3^{2}=9$ is congruent to zero mod $3$ and then the pattern just repeats for $4$ which is congruent to $1$ mod $3$. So we have two examples that are congruent to $1$ mod $3$, one is odd and one is even. So the fact that a number is congruent to $1$ mod $3$ tells us nothing about whether it is odd or even. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are only three alternatives:
\begin{align}
& 0^2 \equiv 0 \\
& 1^2 \equiv 1 \longleftarrow \text{This is a counterexample.} \\
& 2^2 \equiv 1
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3 \iff x \equiv \pm 1 \mod 3 \iff x = 3n\pm 1 \; (n \in \mathbb Z)$.

Numbers of the form $x = 3n \pm 1$ are even if $n$ is odd and odd if $n$ is even.